# How to save any input message from user that send to my line chatbot with google sheet and dialog flow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, line, chatbot

I want to save every message that user input to my line chatbot.The purpose of my chat bot is to receive the information about covid19 because people in my country they usually send covid 19 information to other people by line message. They can share the informations to my chatbot and i will save the informations in google sheet because i want my chatbot to be easy to use.So, I use google sheet as a database and i use dialog-flow . But i don't know how to receive the information like i said ealier .

Comment: Please tell the expected format, i.e what Columns

Answer (score 0):

1. [Deploy a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with the following code
2. Set the `web app URL` as `Webhook URL` in LINE Developers / LINE Manager

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const contents = e.postData.contents;
  const json = JSON.parse(contents);
  // console.log(json);
  const event = json["events"][0];
  if (!event["message"]) { return; }
  const userId = event.source.userId;
  const message = event.message.text;
  
  const id = 'Spreadsheet ID';
  const name = 'Sheet Name';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  sheet.appendRow([userId, message]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This can receive only message not including photo ,is that right?

Comment: Use `event.message.type` to check type and `event.message.originalContentUrl` to get image url.